# Experiences of using Clojure CLJ Record library

Tags: clojure

I have been looking at CLJ record and was wondering what other people's experiences of it were. It looks like the project has not been updated for a while as well. Is it stable, does it have a nice API, and how does it compare against other Clojure database APIs like ClojureQL for example? These are just some of the open questions I have in my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Rails backround, and I found clj-record very similar (to ActiveRecord) and handly to use with Clojure, in fact I built a sample blog app just to see how it felt (available at https://github.com/marklazz/clj-record-blog), and It felt comfortable :)

For Rails devs: Just one minor consideration, compared with ActiveRecord, when you create a record, it doesn't fail to do so if validations don't pass. I asked the author,and it seems to be an open issue (it's evaluating options to improve that). But still, you can validate the model before saving it, and that's what I did on my sample app.

Answer (score 1):

[CLJ Record](https://github.com/duelinmarkers/clj-record) and [ClojureQL](http://www.clojureql.org/) aim at different goals. CLJ record is more like a ORM library whereas ClojureQL is a library to express SQL statements in plain clojure.

Comment: Have you used either of them?

Comment: A played with clojureQL recently and with CLJ record some time ago.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm looking more for experiences of using these on actual projects. Thanks anyway